# Where can I find documentation on the Nominatim geocoding response API?

Tags: geocoding, nominatim

I have begun using the [Nominatim geocoding API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).  This page has reasonable documentation on the request parameters to the service.  However, I can't find anywhere which details the response.  Many of the response fields are obvious, but I would like to know more about osm_type, class, type and their possible values (and what they mean, of course). I would also like to understand what 'importance' refers to.  I cannot find documentation on this output.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sample output:

```
[
{
    "address": {
        "city": "Berlin",
        "city_district": "Mitte",
        "construction": "Unter den Linden",
        "continent": "European Union",
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "country_code": "de",
        "house_number": "1",
        "neighbourhood": "Scheunenviertel",
        "postcode": "10117",
        "public_building": "Kommandantenhaus",
        "state": "Berlin",
        "suburb": "Mitte"
    },
    "boundingbox": [
        "52.5170783996582",
        "52.5173187255859",
        "13.3975105285645",
        "13.3981599807739"
    ],
    "class": "amenity",
    "display_name": "Kommandantenhaus, 1, Unter den Linden, Scheunenviertel, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union",
    "importance": 0.73606775332943,
    "lat": "52.51719785",
    "licence": "Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright",
    "lon": "13.3978352028938",
    "osm_id": "15976890",
    "osm_type": "way",
    "place_id": "30848715",
    "svg": "M 13.397511 -52.517283599999999 L 13.397829400000001 -52.517299800000004 13.398131599999999 -52.517315099999998 13.398159400000001 -52.517112099999999 13.3975388 -52.517080700000001 Z",
    "type": "public_building"
}
]
```

Comment: As I was looking for the exact same answer I skimmed through the [github repo of nominatim](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim).

The web stuff seems to be done mostly in php. There is [`Geocode.php`](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/blob/master/lib/Geocode.php) class that might provide some infos. 

I know this might not be the answer you were looking for but maybe it helps (others).